How to properly handle a number input with ReactJS Hook Form, Zod, and ShadCN UI while avoiding controlled/uncontrolled state issues
I’m working with a form in ReactJS using react-hook-form and Zod for validation, along with ShadCN UI for components. I have a number input field that I want to validate as a number. However, I'm running into issues with the controlled/uncontrolled state when handling this field.
Here’s what I’ve tried and the issues I’m facing:
Default Value Issues:
If I don’t set a defaultValue for the number input, ReactJS throws a warning about switching the input from uncontrolled to controlled.
Setting defaultValue={undefined} also triggers similar issues.
Setting Default to 0:
Setting the defaultValue to 0 avoids the warning, but it causes the field to be pre-filled with 0, which is not ideal. The placeholder is not visible, and the user has to manually delete the 0 before entering their value.
String as Default Value:
Using an empty string "" as the default value isn’t feasible because the input expects a number type, and this causes a type error.
Question:
How can I handle this number input field correctly? I need it to:

Start as an empty field with the placeholder visible.
Validate as a number using Zod.
Avoid warnings about uncontrolled/controlled state.
Ensure that the input doesn’t default to 0, but remains empty until the user inputs a value.

What’s the best approach to achieve this with react-hook-form, Zod, and ShadCN UI, or is there a better way to manage number fields in this context?
Additional Consideration:
I want to handle this field as a true number type without resorting to workarounds like treating it as a string. This is because I want to take full advantage of Zod’s methods for working with numbers (e.g., min, max, int).
This is the current approach I'm using to handle the number input field.
age: z
    .string()
    .min(1, { message: 'Age is required' }) // "Возраст обязателен"
    .transform(value => (value === '' ? '' : Number(value)))
    .refine(value => !isNaN(Number(value)), {
        message: 'Please enter a valid number', // "Введите число"
    }),





function Home() {
    const form = useForm<Schema>({
        mode: 'all',
        resolver: zodResolver(schema),
        defaultValues: {
            age: '',
        },
    });

    function onSubmit(data: z.infer<typeof schema>) {
        console.log('data', data);
    }

    return (
        <div className='h-full p-4 flex items-center justify-center'>
            <Form {...form}>
                <form
                    onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
                    className='w-[500px] border rounded-md p-6 space-y-3'
                >
                    <h3>Form</h3>

                    <FormField
                        control={form.control}
                        name='age'
                        render={({ field }) => (
                            <FormItem className='w-full'>
                                <FormLabel>Age</FormLabel>
                                <FormControl>
                                    <Input type='number' placeholder='Age' {...field} />
                                </FormControl>
                                <FormDescription>Age</FormDescription>
                                <FormMessage />
                            </FormItem>
                        )}
                    />

                    <Button className='w-full'>Submit</Button>
                </form>
                <DevTool control={form.control} />
            </Form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;



You can define the field as number in z schema.
The issue arises if you try to submit the same data. Even though the type of input field is number, the data submitted will be string. To handle this you can typecast the string to number on every onChange event of the field, by wrapping it in the Controller element provided by react-hook-form.
You can replace the FormField component with


<Controller
  control={form.control}
  name="age"
  render={({ field: { value, onChange }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
    <Input
      type="number"
      className="hidden"
      value={value}
      onChange={(e)=>onChange(Number(e.target.value))}
    />
  )}
/>



Now you can perform all validations you want with zod validation.
